# Is it possible to required a subform if main form has been changed/dirtied?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way to require 3 subform fields if the main form has been dirtied? I've googled this with no results so I'm wondering if this is even possible in Access.

I have a MainForm with 5 subforms. One of the subforms is a NoteSubForm where the user inputs a Note (short text), their Initials (combo box), and the NoteDate (Date/Time). Anytime there are changes/updates to the MainForm, I want to require users to put a Note describing the change, Initials, and NoteDate.

I'm thinking there can be a way using If/Then statements and the Dirty property.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: you can use the onChange event of each control in the main form to log changes then before the form is closed check that log and ensure the user has filled out the change details

Comment: `Form.Dirty` is True if any changes has been made to current record, so yeah, you can use that to control changes made. Set it up in all AfterUpdate Events of your textboxes, and then something like `If Form.Dirty=True Then...` and code to force user to put a  Note describing the change, Initials, and NoteDate. More info about [Form.Dirty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-dirty-property-access)

Comment: Do I have to code an event for every control? Is there any event for when anything in the form is changed, before closing, set focus to the note subform and require a note to be inputted?

Comment: I'm afraid yes, you must code for all controls that are editable for users. At least, that what's MSDN says in the website of the link provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar situation, I use a hidden text control on the parent form, and when any of the subforms are updated they change the text in the hidden text control.  Then, when the user tries to save or exit the parent form, I check the hidden control and if it shows updates were made, it opens my pop up form to record the changes that have been made; i.e. your Note, initials and note date.
if the changes are made only on the parent form controls and not in the subforms, the normal form BeforeUpdate process on the parent form catches the changes and allows you to prompt the user for the required note. 
HTH.

**Further details added below**

My forms are order forms, and I'm tracking changes to orders that have already been confirmed to the customer.
On the main form I have an unbound text control called txtRevToDo.  It is not visible and has no default value.  The sub forms are continuous forms so moving between items on the sub form triggers the AfterUpdate code.

In the sub forms AfterUpdate, on each separate sub form,  I have the following code.  I only capture updates to an order where the order line that changed has a cost.  If there is no cost, I don't need to track the change -

```
'set the parent form to dirty so that the changes to contract items can be tracked as a revision to the contract
If Not IsNull(Me.Cost) Then
Me.Parent.txtRevToDo = "Yes"
End If
```

On the main form, the user clicks on a 'Close' button to exit the form.  In the vba code for the OnClick event of that button control, I check the txtRevToDo with this code, which checks the status and sets the main form to be dirty if any trackable changes have been made on the subforms, and it then forces a save which triggers the main form BeforeUpdate code -

```
If Me.txtRevToDo = "Yes" Then
Me.txtPaymentTerms.SetFocus
Me.Dirty = True
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
Else
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Edit Contract Details After Issued"
End If
```

The code in the main form BeforeUpdate which is triggered is this, and this code allows the user to complete the save or go back and make further changes -

```
'Provide the user with the option to save/undo
'changes made to the record in the form


If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this record." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Are you ready to save these changes and create the Contract revision? If you have further changes to make, please select 'No'." _
        , vbYesNo, "Changes Made...") = vbYes Then
       'increase the revision number by 1
        Me.Revision = (Me.Revision + 1)
        Me.txtContractStatus = "Revised"
            'update the Contract Actions table with a record of the action
                 strSQLApprove = ....my sql to update my table 

            'update this flag to reflect that the contract revision has been captured
            Me.txtRevToDo = ""

            'record the revision reason (this opens my pop up form that captures the changes made)
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Edit Contract Revisions"
            Forms![Edit Contract Revisions]!ContractNo = Me.ContractNo
            Forms![Edit Contract Revisions]!txtRevision = Me.Revision
            Forms![Edit Contract Revisions]!RevisedBy = TempVars!EmpID

Else
'update this flag so the revision can be captured even if no further changes are actually made
Me.txtRevToDo = "Yes"

End If
```

Please let me know if you need any more details, I hope that helps you to work out something similar for your situation.

Comment: Would you be able to show an example code of this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure.  I've updated my answer with more details.